# How to write own function to check if two fields are same using form_validation in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter and using 'form_validator' to validate posted data from a form. I am come across a situation where I need to check if 2 fields are having same values. There is already a functionality available

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules( 'new_password', 'New Password', 'trim|required|matches[cpassword]|md5' );
```

I want to know where the function is written for `matches` OR where I can define a new function say `exactly` instead of using `matches`?

Answer (score 1):

It is defined in `system/libraries/form_validation.php`

but i would recommend that instead of making changes in the library, you better extend it!

Comment: yes Sunny I agree. There is already an error message set for `matches` and I can see `function matches` to match two variables. HOw can I use same `function matches` to match 2 fields and not to use error message which is defined `$lang['matches']` in `system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php`

Comment: hmm! i will look for it

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own "Callbacks" functions

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

example from user guide...

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_myown_check');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
}

public function myown_check($str)
{
    if ($str == 'test')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('myown_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

}
```